# Google Cloud CDN doesn't cache from storage bucket?

Tags: css, caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cdn

I've been trying for the past couple of weeks to get this **Load Balancer + Cloud Storage + CDN** combo to work. It just doesn't, at least for me.

Got some static files (2 jpg's, svg's and css's just in case) into a multi-regional US (tried on regional too) bucket to test it out, but it just seems like it doesn't wanna cache at all.

Everytime I try checking it's headers, all I get is this same old boring bucket metadata:

[image]

Cache control are set just fine, you can see the v=2 at the top because I just keep trying to make it cache in different ways and cache strings was the last attempt. Unsucessful as well. LB works because **this IP resolves from it**.

What the hell am I doing wrong?

You can check the links in here:
http://35.227.213.66/style.css
http://35.227.213.66/logo.svg
http://35.227.213.66/1.jpg
http://35.227.213.66/2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are using the correct metadata

```
 Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800
```

It would be interesting to check how many requests have been answered from the CDN and how many from the bucket. You can use a query with 'gcloud beta logging' to check this:

From CDN

```
$ gcloud beta logging read 'resource.type="http_load_balancer" AND "logo.svg" AND httpRequest.cacheHit=true  AND timestamp>="2017-12-04T07:23:00.054257251Z"' | wc -l
```

From your bucket

```
$ gcloud beta logging read 'resource.type="http_load_balancer" AND "logo.svg" AND httpRequest.cacheHit=false  AND timestamp>="2017-12-04T07:23:00.054257251Z"' | wc -l
```